# How to get cursor position details in tkinter Textbox

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-text

I made a text editor in it I made an status bar but a problem I did not know how to get cursor position details like notepad

[image: Notepad image]

*Please help me*

Comment: have you tried `text.index('insert')`? To get line and col use `line, col = text.index('insert').split('.')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you were looking for?

```py
import tkinter

master = tkinter.Tk()

labelframe = tkinter.LabelFrame( master, labelanchor = 's' )
labelframe.grid( row=0, column= 0, sticky = 'nsew' )

text = tkinter.Text( labelframe, width = 80, height= 24 )
text.grid( row=0, column= 0, sticky = 'nsew' )

def rowcol( ev = None ):
    r, c = text.index( 'insert' ).split( '.' )
    labelframe[ 'text' ] = f'{r} | {c}'

text.event_add( '<<REACT>>', *( '<Motion>', '<ButtonRelease>', '<KeyPress>', '<KeyRelease>' ) )
b = text.bind( '<<REACT>>', rowcol )
rowcol( ) # get the ball rolling
text.focus()

master.mainloop()
```

Comment: Your answer is correct but I want to separate line and columns not in float

Comment: That will do it @NaitikSinghal

Comment: Strictly speaking the value from `text.index` is not a float (although it looks like one) it is a row.column string